# Unity3d Terrain Generation Instantiates to much prefabs

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've got a block of code in my 'Update()' function wich gets the active chunk in my scene, when it has found that chunk, it passes those coordinates to the 'generateFromMiddleOfChunk()' function. That function will generate all the chunks in a 3 radius around the player, it does that with 25 'Instantiate()' functions and a formula. But it only should instantiate the chunks where there isn't already a chunk. It doesn't do that, if anyone could take a look at my code, I would greatly appreciate that. I'm sorry for the very repetetive code and alot of `Debug.Log()` functions. Every help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Jordi,

I've got this block of code in my `Update()` function:

```
function Update() {
    var gameObjects : GameObject[] = FindObjectsOfType(GameObject) as GameObject[];
    for (var i = 0; i < gameObjects.length ; i++) {
        if(gameObjects[i].name.Substring(0,6) == "ACTIVE")
            if(gameObjects[i].tag != "Player") {
            var xco = gameObjects[i].transform.position.x;
            var yco = gameObjects[i].transform.position.y;
            var zco = gameObjects[i].transform.position.z;
            Debug.Log(xco.ToString()+yco.ToString()+zco.ToString());
            generateFromMiddleOfChunk(xco, yco, zco);
            }                   
    }
}
```

This block of codes get the chunk in my scene and gets its x, y and z coordinates, it passes those coordinates to the `generateFromMiddleOfChunk()` function. This function looks like this:

```
function generateFromMiddleOfChunk(xco : int, yco : int, zco : int) {
    //V1
    chunk1 = "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk2 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco+chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk3 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk4 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk5 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco+chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk6 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk7 = "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk8 = "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk9 = "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk10= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk11= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk12= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk13= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk14= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk15= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk16= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk17= "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk18= "Chunk (" + xco.ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk19= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk20= "Chunk (" + (xco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk21= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk22= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
    chunk23= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + zco.ToString() + ")";
    chunk24= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco * -1).ToString() + ")";
    chunk25= "Chunk (" + (xco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + yco.ToString() + ", " + (zco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";

    var chunksInScene : GameObject[] = FindObjectsOfType(GameObject) as GameObject[];

    for (var i = 0; i < chunksInScene.length ; i++) {
        if(chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "Chunk" || chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "_TERR" || chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "ACTIV") {
            if(chunksInScene[i].tag != "Player") {
                    var oldXco = chunksInScene[i].transform.position.x;
                    var oldYco = chunksInScene[i].transform.position.y;
                    var oldZco = chunksInScene[i].transform.position.z;

                    oldChunk1 = "Chunk (" + oldXco.ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + oldZco.ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk2 = "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco+chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk3 = "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + oldZco.ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk4 = "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco * -1).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk5 = "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco+chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk6 = "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + oldZco.ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk7 = "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco * -1).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk8 = "Chunk (" + oldXco.ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk9 = "Chunk (" + oldXco.ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco * -1).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk10= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk11= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk12= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + oldZco.ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk13= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco * -1).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk14= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -2).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk15= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk16= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth * -1).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk17= "Chunk (" + oldXco.ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk18= "Chunk (" + oldXco.ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk19= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk20= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk21= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk22= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk23= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + oldZco.ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk24= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco * -1).ToString() + ")";
                    oldChunk25= "Chunk (" + (oldXco + 2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ", " + oldYco.ToString() + ", " + (oldZco + -2 * chunkWidth).ToString() + ")";
            }
        }
    }

    if(oldChunk1.Equals(chunk1)){load1 = false;}
    if(oldChunk2.Equals(chunk2)){load2 = false;}
    if(oldChunk3.Equals(chunk3)){load3 = false;}
    if(oldChunk4.Equals(chunk4)){load4 = false;}
    if(oldChunk5.Equals(chunk5)){load5 = false;}
    if(oldChunk6.Equals(chunk6)){load6 = false;}
    if(oldChunk7.Equals(chunk7)){load7 = false;}
    if(oldChunk8.Equals(chunk8)){load8 = false;}
    if(oldChunk9.Equals(chunk9)){load9 = false;}
    if(oldChunk10.Equals(chunk10)){load10 = false;}
    if(oldChunk11.Equals(chunk11)){load11 = false;}
    if(oldChunk12.Equals(chunk12)){load12 = false;}
    if(oldChunk13.Equals(chunk13)){load13 = false;}
    if(oldChunk14.Equals(chunk14)){load14 = false;}
    if(oldChunk15.Equals(chunk15)){load15 = false;}
    if(oldChunk16.Equals(chunk16)){load16 = false;}
    if(oldChunk17.Equals(chunk17)){load17 = false;}
    if(oldChunk18.Equals(chunk18)){load18 = false;}
    if(oldChunk19.Equals(chunk19)){load19 = false;}
    if(oldChunk20.Equals(chunk20)){load20 = false;}
    if(oldChunk21.Equals(chunk21)){load21 = false;}
    if(oldChunk22.Equals(chunk22)){load22 = false;}
    if(oldChunk23.Equals(chunk23)){load23 = false;}
    if(oldChunk24.Equals(chunk24)){load24 = false;}
    if(oldChunk25.Equals(chunk25)){load25 = false;}
    Debug.Log("1" + chunk1 + oldChunk1 + load1);
    Debug.Log("2" + chunk2 + oldChunk2 + load2);
    Debug.Log("3" + chunk3 + oldChunk3 + load3);
    Debug.Log("4" + chunk4 + oldChunk4 + load4);
    Debug.Log("5" + chunk5 + oldChunk5 + load5);
    Debug.Log("6" + chunk6 + oldChunk6 + load6);
    Debug.Log("7" + chunk7 + oldChunk7 + load7);
    Debug.Log("8" + chunk8 + oldChunk8 + load8);
    Debug.Log("9" + chunk9 + oldChunk9 + load9);
    Debug.Log("10" + chunk10 + oldChunk10 + load10);
    Debug.Log("11" + chunk11 + oldChunk11 + load11);
    Debug.Log("12" + chunk12 + oldChunk12 + load12);
    Debug.Log("13" + chunk13 + oldChunk13 + load13);
    Debug.Log("14" + chunk14 + oldChunk14 + load14);
    Debug.Log("15" + chunk15 + oldChunk15 + load15);
    Debug.Log("16" + chunk16 + oldChunk16 + load16);
    Debug.Log("17" + chunk17 + oldChunk17 + load17);
    Debug.Log("18" + chunk18 + oldChunk18 + load18);
    Debug.Log("19" + chunk19 + oldChunk19 + load19);
    Debug.Log("20" + chunk20 + oldChunk20 + load20);
    Debug.Log("21" + chunk21 + oldChunk21 + load21);
    Debug.Log("22" + chunk22 + oldChunk22 + load22);
    Debug.Log("23" + chunk23 + oldChunk23 + load23);
    Debug.Log("24" + chunk24 + oldChunk24 + load24);
    Debug.Log("25" + chunk25 + oldChunk25 + load25);
    /*    
    //V1
    if(load1){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    //V2
    if(load2){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load3){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load4){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load5){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load6){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load7){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load8){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load9){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    //V3 
    if(load10){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load11){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load12){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load13){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load14){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -2, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load15){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load16){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth * -1, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load17){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load18){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load19){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load20){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + chunkWidth, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load21){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco + 2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load22){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco + chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load23){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load24){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco * -1), Quaternion.identity);}
    if(load25){Instantiate(terrains[Random.Range(0,terrains.length)], Vector3(xco + 2 * chunkWidth, yco, zco + -2 * chunkWidth), Quaternion.identity);}     
    */
}
```

Comment: Wow... There is a much easier and efficient way of doing this... Google voxel terrain generation :)

Comment: Hmmmm, I see, that is indeed much more easy to make, but I don't want my terrain to be blocky

Comment: Oh... I assumed you were doing a blocked terrain because of "cube" which is in this questions title... The concept for normal terrain is still similar so you could figure it out utilizing the same techniques just altered...

Comment: Okay thank you for your help :) But do you see anything that might cause this weird behaviour? I'll change the title, that is indeed confusing.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I just removed the javascript tag since unityscript isn't javascript

Comment: Okay thank you, you love editing my posts right? ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/177931/tutorial-minecraft-chunks.html

This is a link to the UnityAnswers with a tutorial on how to chunk in Unity3D . You can look ther efor more information ,and hopefully an answer to your quetsion.